# Why does Python return 0 for this & operation?

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-operators

I'm learning Python and messing around with operations when I tried

```
>>> 14 & 16
0
>>> 0b1110 & 0b10000
0
```

In my head it would look like this:

```
>>> 0b1110 & 0b10000
1
```

From my understanding the & operator compares the 2 numbers in bit form to see if each bit is 1 and if so assigns a 1 to the returned value.

So why would this return 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Why would it be 16? The output is `0b00000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bits are *right*-aligned (padding with 0 on the left as necessary), so `14 & 16` compares as

```
   1110
& 10000
  -----
  00000
```

not

```
   1110
&  10000
   -----
   10000  (16, not 1)
```